# Не работают Writer и Scanner с сокетами

Tags: java, сокет, scanner

```java
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
new Thread(() -> {
    try(Socket socket = new Socket()) {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9000), 2000);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            writer.write("" + i);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();
Socket socketOfServer = serverSocket.accept();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socketOfServer.getInputStream());
while(scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Ничего не выводится. Сканер ничего не принимает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходим `writer.flush()` после всех `writer.write("" + i)`.

С целью оптимизации в процессе работы потока данные перед записью могут накапливаться в буфере. Для его очистки и принудительной записи данных используется метод `flush`. Обычно данный метод неявно вызывается, когда накапливается достаточно данных в буфере, а так же перед закрытием потока.

Comment: А ещё, наверное, закрыть его надо.

Comment: И разве нельзя `flush()` написать только в конце один раз?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Его как раз и не нужно всякий раз без явной надобности вызывать - слишком много лишних накладных расходов (можно проверить даже локальным копированием файлов по байту/символу с вызовом flush после каждого байта/символа и без него, потому как под буфером понимаются не только буферы в джава классах, но и буферы ОС, буферы жестких дисков и прочие). Так что flush необходимо вызывать лишь при необходимости зафиксировать какое-то состояние  (если достаточно один раз в конце, то можно один раз в конце), ну и при закрытие потока flush вызывается автоматически.

Comment: Вы просто написали "после всех". Я думал, что вы имеете в виду, "после каждого".